# Error 'Cannot Convert double to int'

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, type-conversion

I have what seems to me as a weird issue with my code. I have a method that performs a simple query and returns the result. I'm trying to return the value as a double but I get an error:

> CS0266    Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'int'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I'm not trying to do any conversions so I don't understand what the issue is.
Here is the calling code:

```
  double displacement = sqLite.GetDisplacement( transItem.Item.Name );
```

and here is the code that is called:

```
public int GetDisplacement( string item )
{
    double dDisposition = 0;
    string sSql = "SELECT [Displacement] FROM [Items] WHERE [Name] = '" + item + "';";

    using ( var dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection( sConnectionString ) )
    {
        try
        {
            dbConnection.Open();
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand( sSql, dbConnection );
            object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            dDisposition = Convert.ToDouble( result );

        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            MessageBox.Show( "Error retreiving displacement information: " + e.ToString() );
        }

    }

    return dDisposition; // This is where I get the error

}
```

I'm not trying to convert anything, everything is declared as a double. I've tried to clean and rebuild the solution several times to no avail. What am I missing?

Comment: `public int ...`

Comment: your function is declared as returning `int` so, `return dDisposition;` is trying to convert a double to int

Comment: A word of advice for when you encounter this in the future. Read your code **out loud** and you will very quickly discover the problem.

Comment: Thanks guys, that was the problem I just didn't see it.

Comment: Also, **stop using apps hungarian**. Annotating variables with their types is unnecessary in C#. If you want to annotate a variable with its type, make it meaningful, like `itemsCount` or `itemsIndex`, never `itemsInt`; we don't know whether an int is a count or an index. If you want to know whether a variable is a double or a string, *look at its declaration*, not at its name.

Comment: Also your code has a SQL injection security hole.

Comment: Also, why is the variable that holds the displacement called "disposition"?

Answer (score 1):

The method declaration states that an `int` value will be returned:

```
public int GetDisplacement (string item)
```

But on the code, the return statement is returning a variable of type `double`:

```
double dDisposition = 0;

// Your code here

return dDisposition;
```

You have to change one or the other, so basically change the return type:

```
public double GetDisplacement (string item)
```

Or the type of the `dDisposition` variable and the [converter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf1aw27b(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int dDisposition = 0;

// Your code here
dDisposition = Convert.ToInt32(result);
// More of your code here

return dDisposition;
```

Comment: A cast to int would be more idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks @Nahuel Ianni. I knew I was missing something.